# Could anyone help me find this page?

Tags: java, oracle, reference, sun

This following link is broken since Sun is acquired by Oracle. Does anyone know what this page is about and where I can find it? Thanks!

http://developer.java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/RefObj/

Answer (score 3):

It's Monica Pawlan's August 1998 article "Reference Objects and Garbage Collection", currently online at http://pawlan.com/monica/articles/refobjs/.